# html - how to remove the index.html from the URL

Tags: html

I am trying to remove the ***index.html*** from the URL.

---

I want to change this `domain.com/projects/index.html`

to this `domain.com/projects/`

---

I tried the `/` method and the `.htaccess` method, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Could someone please tell me how chould i do that ?

Thanks alot.

Comment: we really cant answer the question because you have given us no context or code sample

Comment: Which server are you using? Provide some more details

Comment: @benams i'm using the gamejolt.io hosting

Answer (score 0):

That's because your index.html file is not in your root directory, its in your projects directory.
so instead of changing it to '/' change it to 'projects'.